# Network icon not shown

Tags: networking, network-manager, icons

After an update in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS trusty the network icon is missing.
The network is working ok just only the icon is not shown in the top bar.

This is the second time it happens after an update this month (the first time the network was turned off so I had to turn on the network manually and wait for the update for the problem to be fixed from the offical repositories) but now it doesn't work (but only affects to the icon).
So I have two questions.
First. How to fix this?
Second. I have the "proposed" repository turned off..so why is this happening?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an new update the system is working ok again.

The first time I had to:

1. ifconfig eth0 up
2. dhclient eth0

When you have connection then try to update the system. Hopefully it will be solved in next update.

Important.  Set the "proposed" repository turned off.